# Generating images without graphic toolkit

Tags: svg, rendering

I am thinking about creating a CLI tool for generating images, similar to Graphviz or PlantUML (Preferably in Rust, but the concept should apply to other languages as well). The input is some text-based description format, the output should be either a raster format or some vector format.

I am wondering how I should represent this internally in my application? If I use a graphics toolkit, I have all the tools for generating widgets, laying out text available, but of course, this is usually tight to a output device, so I would rather not use that.

Is there something similar for internal use? Should I just represent everything internally directly as SVG and then use an SVG renderer to generate a raster format? But I guess then I still don't have any “understanding“ of the layout in my application, e.g. for overlaying, text-wrapping etc.

Thanks

Comment: How will it be different from Graphviz, PlantUML, TikZ, SVG and/or gpic/dpic?

Comment: Well, in general it will be the same, but I am interested in the underlying concept.

Comment: One advantage to SVG output is it is textual - easier to read & debug.  If you grab the Graphviz source (http://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/) look at plugin/core/gvrender_core_svg.c to see how it generates SVG  (there are other renderers for other output formats)  The pic/gpic/dpic language is smaller & has 3 (or more) open source implementations.  You might learn from them.